# How to create a table in r similar to a pivot table?

Tags: r, pivot

I have a table of data containing an ID, a city and the status.

```
| ID   | City     | Status      |
| ---- | -------- |
| H1   | Exeter   | Approved    |
| O9   | London   | No decision |
| D7   | Cardiff  | Rejected    |
| B8   | Bath     | Rejected    |
| Z4   | London   | Approved    |
| L9   | Bristol  | Approved    |
| Z3   | Exeter   | Rejected    |
| T6   | London   | No decision |
| E1   | Bristol  | Approved    |
| N8   | Bath     | Approved    |
```

I would like to create a table in R that is similar to a pivot table to show how many fit into each category. Similar to the below....

```
| Status      | Exeter | London | Cardiff | Bath | Bristol |
| -------     | ------ | ------ | ---- -- | ---- | ------- |
| Approved    |   1    |   1    |    0    |   1  |    2    |
| No decision |   0    |   2    |    0    |   0  |    0    | 
| Rejected    |   1    |   0    |    1    |   1  |    0    |
```

Comment: try `table(rev(df[-1]))`